# Cannot find user without id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

i'm getting this error for my products and user table.

--Couldn't find user without an id

```
def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
end
```

I have nested the routes like so..

```
   resources :users do
   resources :products do
    resources :reviews
    end
   end
```

and here is my products controller..

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

before_action :require_signin, except: [:index, :show]
before_action :set_user

def index
  @products = @user.products
end

def show
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end

def edit
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  if @product.update(product_params)
    redirect_to [@user, @product], notice: "Product successfully updated!"
  else
    render :edit
  end
end

def new
  @product = @user.products.new
end

def create
  @product = @user.products.new(product_params)
  @product.user = current_user
  if @product.save
    redirect_to user_products_path(@product, @user), notice: "Product successfully created!"
  else
    render :new
  end
end

def destroy
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  @product.destroy
  redirect_to user_products_path(@product, @user), alert: "Product successfully deleted!"
end


private

def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :posted_on, :price, :location, :category)
end

def set_user
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
end

end
```

All i am trying to do is associate the user and product so the product belongs_to user, and the user has_many products.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user
has_many :reviews

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_secure_password
  has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :products, dependent: :destroy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other users have mentioned the params[:user_id] value is probably nil.

That said, you already appear to have a current_user defined in the scope of the controller. I see it referenced in the create action. I'd bet that it was set by the require_sign_in before_action. Given what I think you are trying to do, it probably makes your set_user before_action a bit redundant.

You can probably just refer to current_user in your controller anywhere you are currently using @user.  Alternatively, you might set @user = current_user in the set_user before_action.

**SideNote**:

Looking a bit closer at your create action:

```
def create
  @product = @user.products.new(product_params)
  @product.user = current_user
  if @product.save
    redirect_to user_products_path(@product, @user), notice: "Product successfully created!"
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe doing something like @model.association.new sets the model_id for the newly created association object so I would change the two lines

```
@product = @user.products.new(product_params)
@product.user = current_user
```

to simply be

```
@product = current_user.products.new(product_params)
```

Answer (score 1):

For any action of your controller you should pass user_id param.
The reason of error is params[:user_id] equal nil